# Mono: is it possible co create xaml based chromeless window that would run on Mac Win and Linux from same code base?

Tags: c#, xaml, mono, cross-platform

I wonder how to create windowless\chromeless app in Mono: is it possible co create xaml based chromeless window that would run on Mac Win and Linux from same code base?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Mono support XAML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798550/does-mono-support-xaml)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, I *could* do this on windows and linux, not sure about OSX.

[image]

See MoonBase - https://github.com/inorton/MoonBase.  This was all however quite a few months ago. I'm unsure of the current state of moonlight and moonlight-desktop (on which this is based).

I managed to create cross-plaform MVVM example apps that used [xaml from the same sources](https://github.com/inorton/MoonBase/blob/master/Examples/hello/Views/Views/Home.xaml).

Comment: Grate one=) what about windowless/chromeless?

Comment: Well, you can make a gtk window borderless I think.